# Не меняется цвет объекта при получении урона. Цвет становится равен 191, 191, 191 по RGB

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Хочу сделать так, чтобы цвет менялся от уровня здоровья (от белого к чёрному), но при получении урона в любом количестве, цвет застывает на 191,191,191 по RGB.
baseHealth - изначальное здоровье
health - здоровье в реальном времени
Rw - преобразовывает здоровье в цветовой код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerColor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public int baseHealth;
    public int health;
    public int Rw;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        Rw = (health * 255) / baseHealth;
        player.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(Rw, Rw, Rw, 255);
    }
}
```

Comment: `float ColorValue = health/(float)baseHealth;`